# Bash while loop sed replace

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have a weird problem here. I think I'm 99% there. I just have a small syntax and or logic error somewhere when trying to do the following:

So I have a manifest file with a bunch of MD5 sums. Don't worry, the sums are just for comparison, not security. The file looks something like this:

```
puppy.cfg=324327437483274834783204723
kitty.cfg=7893703274r0327403247032472
etc.
```

The "Manifest" function gets called and gets passed a value. It gets passed a file name which is referred to as an ID (IDA). The function then calculates the current sum of that file (IDA). It then looks at every line in the manifest file until it finds the matching file ID (IDA=IDB). When it finds the matching ID is compares the current sum against the sum in the manifest file (SUMA vs SUMB). If there is no difference, then the function just closes out and does nothing. If it does detect a difference, then the function "should" update the manifest file with the "current" sum. This part of the function is not currently working. It's doing something weird and mashing together variables and not changing anything. I know I just missed something simple. Can someone help please?

```
function MANIFEST.CHECK {
  local IDA="$1"
  local SUMA=$(md5sum $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  while read LINE; do
    local IDB="`echo $LINE | cut -d"=" -f1`";
    local SUMB="`echo $LINE | cut -d"=" -f2`";
    if [ "$IDA" = "$IDB" ]; then
      if [ ! "$SUMA" = "$SUMB" ]; then
        while read LINE; do
          sed "s%$SUMB%$IDA\=$SUMA%" var/manifest
        done < <(grep -v '#' var/manifest)
        echo "The file is/was different."
        return
      fi
    fi
  done < <(grep -v '#' var/manifest)
}

### START SCRIPT ###
MANIFEST.CHECK puppy.cfg
```

Comment: Just checking, were you expecting sed to change the file 'in place' (i.e. like an editor)? It does not; it just sends a modified copy to stdout.

Comment: That explains why I saw the "mashed" output. Hmm im not sure where to go from here then. How would you recommend replacing a single line in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you could replace the inner `while` loop with a single `sed` like this:

```
function MANIFEST.CHECK {
  local IDA="$1"
  local SUMA=$(md5sum $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  while read LINE; do
    local IDB="`echo $LINE | cut -d"=" -f1`";
    local SUMB="`echo $LINE | cut -d"=" -f2`";
    if [ "$IDA" = "$IDB" ]; then
      if [ ! "$SUMA" = "$SUMB" ]; then
        sed -i "s%$SUMB%$SUMA%" var/manifest
        echo "The file is/was different."
        return
      fi
    fi
  done < <(grep -v '#' var/manifest)
}
```

I would make some other improvements too, and rewrite the script like this:

```
manifest=var/manifest
function MANIFEST.CHECK {
    local IDA="$1"
    local SUMA=$(md5sum "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    local IDB SUMB
    while read LINE; do
        IFS== read IDB SUMB <<< "$LINE"
        if [ "$IDA" = "$IDB" ]; then
            if [ "$SUMA" != "$SUMB" ]; then
                sed -i "s%$SUMB%$SUMA%" "$manifest"
                echo "The file is/was different."
                break
            fi
        fi
    done < <(grep -v '#' "$manifest")
}
MANIFEST.CHECK puppy.cfg
```